# How to use each_serializer with nil in the array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a controller with code that looks something like the following. The idea is to take an array of user IDs, and return matching user objects in the order the IDs were given.

```
def index
  user_ids = params[:user_ids]
  users = User.where(id: user_ids)
  users_by_id = users.inject({}) do |hash, user|
    hash[user.id] = user
    hash
  end
  sorted_users = user_ids.map do |user_id|
    users_by_id[user_id]
  end
  render json: sorted_users, each_serializer: ::UserSerializer
end
```

This code fails if a user does not exist for a given user ID with the following error:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass:
```

How I can implement this function so that for all invalid user IDs, the final array simply contains a null?

For example, if the client requests `/users?user_ids[]=1&users_ids[]=2&user_ids[]=3`, and records exist only for IDs `1` and `2`, I want the JSON response to look something like:

```
[
  {id: 1, name: "Alice"},
  {id: 2, name: "Bob"},
  null
]
```

Comment: the whole logic you use to set `users_by_id` can be simplified to `users_by_id = users.group_by(&:id)`

Comment: Not quite, since the `users_by_id` is a map from `id -> User` not `id -> [User]`

Comment: `index_by(&:id)` in that case

Comment: try the `compact` method like this `sorted_users.compact`... it'll remove all nil values from the array

Comment: I don't want to remove `nil` values. I want them to be part of the JSON array, but as `null` values. I've updated the question with an example.